# A very strange error here: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

Hey guys i meet dereferencing pointer to incomplete type. it's very strange. I need help
Graph.h //an undirected weighted graph algorithm interface

```
typedef int Vertex;

typedef struct {
   Vertex v;
   Vertex w;
   int weight;
} Edge;

Edge mkEdge(Vertex, Vertex, int);

typedef struct graphRep  *Graph;

Graph newGraph(int nV);

void insertE(Graph g, Edge e);
```

Graph.c // post a part of implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Graph.h"

struct graphRep {
   int V;
   int E;
   int **edges;
 }


 int validV(Graph g, Vertex v);

 int validV(Graph g, Vertex v){
     return (v >= 0 && v < g->V);
 }
 // Create an edge from v to w
 Edge mkEdge(Vertex v, Vertex w,int weight) {
      assert(v >= 0 && w >= 0  );
      Edge e = {v,w,weight};
      return e;
 }
Graph newGraph(int nV) {

   assert(nV >= 0);
   int i,j;
   Graph g = malloc(sizeof(struct graphRep));
   assert(g!=NULL);
   if(nV==0){
      g->edges = NULL;
   } else {
      g->edges = malloc(nV*sizeof(int *));
   }
   for(i = 0; i < nV;i++){
        g->edges[i] = malloc(nV * sizeof(int));
        assert(g->edges[i] != NULL);
        for(j = 0; j < nV; j++){
        g->edges[i][j] = 0;
        }
   }
   g->V = nV;
   g->E = 0;
   return g;
}
```

testGraph.c // a part of test

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Graph.h"
int main(void){
      printf("boundary test for newGraph\n");
      Graph g = newGraph(0);
      assert(g!=NULL);
      assert(g->V == 0 && g->E ==0 && g->edges == NULL);
      printf("test passed!\n");
      free(g);
      return 0;
 }
```

I am so confused because i did
     typedef struct graphRep *Graph
     which means it is a struct with pointer.
But still got these mistakes

```
 wagner % gcc -Wall -Werror Graph.c testGraph.c
 In file included from testGraph.c:3:0:
 testGraph.c: In function 'main':
 testGraph.c:30:12: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     assert(g->V == 0 && g->E ==0 && g->edges == NULL);
             ^
 testGraph.c:30:25: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     assert(g->V == 0 && g->E ==0 && g->edges == NULL);
                          ^
 testGraph.c:30:37: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     assert(g->V == 0 && g->E ==0 && g->edges == NULL);
                                      ^
```

somebody help me T T

Comment: struct graphRep is unknown to "testGraph.c" file. If you want to hide details of graphRep then you can use  opaque pointer concept.

Answer (score 2):

`testGraph.c` cannot see the struct defined into `Graph.c`

Move `struct graphRep` into the `Graph.h` interface file.

Comment: but for a good ADTs it should be hidden. I have done  a few of graph homework which tutor didn't allow to change the interface and they all do fine

Comment: You can do that, but you cannot dereference a pointer to that `struct`. So all access to that struct must be implemented by `get/set` function in `Graph.c` file and make available for others using `.h` interface file.